# Cannot call suspend function from launch

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Im new to kotlin coroutines and I'm trying to call a suspend function from oncreate using launch. But the code would not execute.

```
launch {
    callSomeApi()
}

suspend fun callSomeApi() {
    withContext(Dispatcher.IO) {
        //perform network call
    }
}
```

It says suspend function should only be called from a coroutine or other suspend function. Although Im calling it from launch. Please let me know what am I doing wrong?
[please see attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3Y91.png)

Comment: Are you sure that's `kotlinx.coroutines.launch` and not some other function called `launch`? Try to go to its definition.

Comment: Yes. It is kotlinx.coroutines.launch

Answer (score 2):

You have to do like this :

```
  CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
            someSuspendFunction()
        }
```

this way you assign a CoroutineScope to manage the coroutines processes.
Keep in mind that you have to import coroutine dependencies completely:

```
    // coroutines
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.0.0'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-adapter:0.9.2'
```

Comment: I have added the exact same dependencies. But still Im getting the same error. Please look into the question I have attached the error screenshot. Can you let me know what version of kotlin plugin are you using?

Comment: I am using the latest ,1.3.40

Comment: could you please paste all the involved code, where are you putting all these codes?

Comment: it's really weird, I tested the code above in any classes, and no error is visible!.

Comment: Okay turns out it was the kotlin gradle plugin that was causing all the problem. I updated the gradle plugin 1.3.31 and the error is gone. Thanks!

Comment: cool, yes!, Gradle and headache has some closed relationship!.